Left join 2 tables and return many duplicate rows
I have 2 tables
table1
emp  type
tom   1
tom   2

table2
emp  grade
tom   a
tom   b
tom   c

Expect return
emp  type grade
tom   1     a
tom   2     b
tom         c

query look correct but not quite right

select table1.emp , table1.type, table2.emp, table2.grade
from table1
left join table2 on table1.emp = table2.emp

return
emp  type grade
tom   1     a         
tom   1     b         
tom   1     c         
tom   2     a         
tom   2     b         
tom   2     c         


Why, in your expected result, is grade "a" in the same row as type 1 and not type 2, for example? Why doesn't grade "c" have a matching type?

You haven't answered the question on why type of 1 matches with a and 2 goes to b etc. But based on your example it seems like you just want to match them up lexicographically. Assuming that's true, this is one way you can accomplish your example expected return then:
WITH _table2Sorted AS
(
    SELECT
        emp,
        grade,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp ORDER BY grade) AS GradeSortId
    FROM table2
)

SELECT
    T2.emp,
    T1.type,
    T2.grade
FROM _table2Sorted AS T2
LEFT JOIN table1 AS T1
    ON T2.emp = T1.emp
    AND T2.GradeSortId = T1.type;

Note this assumes you want every row from table2 but only the matching rows from table1.
Also, you could obviously just select directly from _table2Sorted and use the GradeSortId as the type for a simpler query, in this specific case. But this also works if you had a more complex use case where you needed other columns from table1 as well.

Your key emp has multiple matching rows for each emp in table2.  The engine has no way to know that

1 maps onto a
and 2 maps onto b.

What it is returning is correct.  To get the answer you want, you could add the type field to table2
